# how can we set a scrollview's content size based on textview content?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my application, i have taken a textview and an imageview.Based on the content in textview, how can we manage content size of scrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  // scrollPanel fit to the text view

    scrollPanel.frame=self.view.frame (or) view.frame;
    scrollPanel.contentSize = CGSizeMake(textview.frame.width,textview.frame.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the content size to be at least large enough to scroll across the entire `textview`, you can determine the correct size by adding the `textView` to the `scrollview`, then setting the `contentSize` to something like

```
scrollPanel.contentSize = CGSizeMake( txtView.frame.origin.x + txtView.frame.size.width, txtView.frame.origin.y + txtView.frame.size.height)
```

This will set the content width to be as wide as the `txtView`, plus the left-hand positioning offset, and the height to be the same as the `txtView`'s height plus its distance from the top of the `scrollPanel`.